# Associate a different program for opening my output file in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, flash, file-association

I just started using linux (Ubuntu) and switched to IntelliJ as my new IDE. I just finished setting up my first project, but I can't find where to change the default program for opening my .swf output file.

Right now it keeps opening my file with 'Movie Player' which doesen't even recognize .swf files.

Is this a linux setting I have to change (default program for filetype) Or a setting in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's possible to override the application in the [Run/Debug configuration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configurations.html). For Flash the setting is **Launch with**, for Haxe it would be **Alternative executable**.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up here:`Settings > IDE SETTINGS > File Types`. This will change the view mode for different file types. As on my windows machine, `.swf` is not in the list. This may indicate that you have to change this file's default program in your OS (Ubuntu).